# How do I fix NaN result from adding numbers using Jquery in Contact Form 7

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have some `JQuery` scripts that I am running on a `CF7` form.
The `ID` in the `CF7` form match the var called to be used by `JQuery`.
I am getting no result, but I cant understand why its not a number.

I have tried substituting the `CF7` `ID` for an actual number and it works, but only if I use multiply. If I try and add the two id items together I get no result

```js
// this should add benefits to prelim income to give finalincome
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var prelimincome;
  var benefit;
  var finalincome;

  jQuery("#benefit").on("change", function() {
    benefit = this.value;

    finalincome = (benefit) + (prelimincome);
    jQuery("#finalincome").val(finalincome.toFixed());
  });
});
```

I am expecting a numerical answer to adding the two `ID`'s but I get no answer.  I expect the answer to be prelimincome + benefit = finalincome

Answer (score 1):

try

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   var prelimincome =0;
   var benefit=0;
   var finalincome=0;

  jQuery("#benefit").on("change", function() {
     benefit= this.value ;
     finalincome= (parseFloat(prelimincome) + parseFloat(benefit)).toFixed(2);  // decimal

///  finalincome= parseInt(prelimincome) + parseInt(benefit);  // integer
     finalincome=(benefit)+(prelimincome);
     jQuery("#finalincome").val(finalincome);

 }); 


});
```

Comment: Thanks for the code to try. The top piece of code gives no answer and the bottom piece of code gives NaN

Comment: @Speedy what? I didn't get your comment

Comment: Sorry i pasted by mistake. The top code gives no answer and the bottom line of code gives NaN

Comment: I am manually adding the value for prelimincome and benefit straight into the form. I will post the cf7 ID thats being called

Comment: [tel prelimincome id:prelimincome]   [tel benefit id:benefit]  [tel finalincome id:finalincome]   I am using tel so that the big number keypad shows up on mobile

Comment: If the code you've provided is the actual code you're using, I don't actually see where the variable prelimincome is being assigned a value, that is the reason why you're getting NaN. Performing primitve operations between unassigned variables and Numbers results in NaN.

Comment: @Speedy I think the value of prelimincome in unfefined thats why you getting NaN, set 0 by default then try

Comment: I have tried predefining the variable in cf7 like this [tel prelimincome id:prelimincome "0"] and using the same script, but still not working.

Comment: I really want to call prelim income from another script I have on the same page that is working which uses similar code, but it broke down when I added the code I pasted above which is why I seperated the code to run with a manually added number to see if I could figure out why it was failing. So I think its definitely something to do with how I can assigning a value to prelimincome